# DataGridView_DefaultValuesNeeded not assigning values

Tags: c#, events, datagridview

I have a DataGridView being populated from a SQL database (2005 I believe).  When the user clicks on the empty new row at the bottom of the view, I want to default some of the values.  I am using the DefaultValuesNeeded event to do this, but it is not always assigning the values.

For example, if I use the below code,

```
private void dgvCharts_DefaultValuesNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{            
        e.Row.Cells["ID"].Value = "";         
        e.Row.Cells["Active"].Value = true;
        e.Row.Cells["ChartType"].Value = cboChartTypes.Items[0];                
}
```

after the handler fires, the "ID" cell will still be null, "Active" will be true, and "ChartType" will have the correct value ("ChartType" is a combobox column, cboChartTypes is the combobox I created as a template for it).  On the Other hand, if I move "ID" to the bottom, all 3 are null after completing the event.  Same if I remove the ID assignment entirely.

I've checked that none of the rows are read only.  But for the life of me, there is no reason that starting with a failed assignment should effect how/if the others are assigned.  Can anyone explain this?  And how can I correct it?

Edit:
Here is the code that binds the query to the datagridview.

```
string qSelect = "SELECT kitChartId,Active,ChartName,ChartType,RetireDate FROM kit_charts INNER JOIN charts on kit_charts.chart = charts.chartId where kit = @kit";
SqlCommand selectCmd = new SqlCommand(qSelect);
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.open();
    selectCmd.Connection = conn;
    using(SqlDataReader dr = selectCmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);
        display.DataSource = dt;
        display.Refresh();
    }
}
```

When a new row is added to the datagridview I want to add a row to the kit_charts table once the user hits the save button.

Comment: clicking on the empty row should not do anything.. so what are you trying to do.. also sounds like a binding issue.. can you show where you are rebinding the datagridview ? I think you need to understand how Binding works.. you get data from the sql query.. then you want to display it to the user via databinding to the datagridview.. so what if they click an empty row.. common sense should tell you that there is no data for that row.. can you show the query and code to how you are binding..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure exactly what was going on, but the behavior is now correct.  I added

```
dt.Columns["kitChartId"].AllowDBNull = true;
dt.Columns["kitChartId"].AutoIncrement = false;
```

between `dt.Load(dr);` and `display.DataSource = dt;`

I removed `e.Row.Cells["ID"].Value = "";` from the DefaultValuesNeeded handler because without auto increment, it defaulted to a null or empty string, which suited my save function.